# Json file not returns ("The provided key element does not match the schema")

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloud9

I am working in AWS Cloud9 environment using DynamoDB written in Python. When running .json file, I keep receiving the error:

**`An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema`**

The DynamoDB table has already been created, and I am trying to use the .json file to enter data.

[image]

**Here is the .json file txt:**

```
{
"Movies": [
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Title": {"S": "Top Gun: Maverick"},
                "Rating": {"S": "8.3/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 10m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Drama"},
                "Description": {"S":"After thirty years, Maverick is still pushing the envelope as a top naval aviator, but must confront ghosts of his past when he leads TOP GUNs elite graduates on a mission that demands the ultimate sacrifice from those chosen to fly it."}
            }
        }    
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Title": {"S": "Extraction 2"},
                "Rating": {"S": "7.0/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 2m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Thriller"},
                "Description": {"S":"After barely surviving his grievous wounds from his mission in Dhaka, Bangladesh, Tyler Rake is back, and his team is ready to take on their next mission."}
            }
        }    
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Title": {"S": "Free Guy"},
                "Rating": {"S": "7.1/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "1h 55m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Adventure, Comedy"},
                "Description": {"S":"When Guy, a bank teller, learns that he is a non-player character in a bloodthirsty, open-world video game, he goes on to become the hero of the story and takes the responsibility of saving the world."}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Title": {"S": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"},
                "Rating": {"S": "8.8/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 58m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Adeventure, Drama"},
                "Description": {"S":"A meek Hobbit from the Shire and eight companions set out on a journey to destroy the powerful One Ring and save Middle-earth from the Dark Lord Sauron."}
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is copy of error message:**

```
voclabs:~/environment $ aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://movies.json

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

At this point I am not understanding why I am still getting this error message and any advice or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like the table has a Partition Key of "Movie (String)".  It will not be auto-generated, so it needs to be provided for each item as well.  I'd suggest adding the key to each item of the batch request like this:

```
{
"Movies": [
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Movie": {"S": "Top Gun: Maverick"},
                "Title": {"S": "Top Gun: Maverick"},
                "Rating": {"S": "8.3/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 10m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Drama"},
                "Description": {"S":"After thirty years, Maverick is still pushing the envelope as a top naval aviator, but must confront ghosts of his past when he leads TOP GUNs elite graduates on a mission that demands the ultimate sacrifice from those chosen to fly it."}
            }
        }    
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Movie": {"S": "Extraction 2"},
                "Title": {"S": "Extraction 2"},
                "Rating": {"S": "7.0/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 2m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Thriller"},
                "Description": {"S":"After barely surviving his grievous wounds from his mission in Dhaka, Bangladesh, Tyler Rake is back, and his team is ready to take on their next mission."}
            }
        }    
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Movie": {"S": "Free Guy"},
                "Title": {"S": "Free Guy"},
                "Rating": {"S": "7.1/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "1h 55m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Adventure, Comedy"},
                "Description": {"S":"When Guy, a bank teller, learns that he is a non-player character in a bloodthirsty, open-world video game, he goes on to become the hero of the story and takes the responsibility of saving the world."}
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "PutRequest": {
            "Item": {
                "Movie": {"S": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"},
                "Title": {"S": "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"},
                "Rating": {"S": "8.8/10"},
                "Length": {"S": "2h 58m" },
                "Genre": {"S": "Action, Adeventure, Drama"},
                "Description": {"S":"A meek Hobbit from the Shire and eight companions set out on a journey to destroy the powerful One Ring and save Middle-earth from the Dark Lord Sauron."}
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I've left the duplicate Title in there, but depending on your needs you might be able to remove it.  **The key takeaway here is providing the name/value expected by your primary partition key.  In this case "Movie: {"S": "Movie name goes here"}"**